# Обязательна ли командная строка новичку?

Tags: javascript, java, командная-строка

О бязательно ли знать/уметь пользоваться командной строкой для работы с js или java? Можно ли обойтись без нее?

Пояснение: начинаю постигать основы программирования, интересует JS и Java, все ещё не могу определиться, что интересней. Но каждый раз при прохождении каких-либо курсов или туториолов, рано или поздно всплывает тема взаимодействия с командой строкой, что на линуксе, что на Винде. Сначала глаза загорелись "О круто, буду как кулхацкер", поставил убунту, начал осваивать, но понял, что командная строка вызывает дикую боль в голове, абсолютно неудобно и непривычно и неинтуитивно. Вернулся на Винду, и вот опять, настойка окружения для того же js, опять требует манипуляций с ком.строкой. Понимаю, что если бы остался на линуксе,она бы так или иначе нужна была, но все же твердо решил, что на данный момент для меня винда-ванлав.

Comment: Привет.
1. Я с фронтом не дружу, но про JS из командной строки не слышал;
2. В java не обязательно чисто помнить все команды, важно понимать, что они значат, если читаешь, кем то написанный скрипт по развертыванию приложения. Даже не имея опыта собственного написания скриптов, иногда появляется необходимость запустить, что-то из командной строки. Например используя IDE все равно через терминал приходиться запускать liquibase.jar, передавать параметры и работать с update/rollback.

Comment: Считаю не обязательно ее использовать повсеместно, важно понять принцип работы с Java приложениями, использованием(понятием) ключей и передачей параметров на вход приложениям.

Comment: Тем более, что при работе с Java или другими языками, так или иначе приходиться работать с окружением, и за частую с командной строкой.

Comment: Ничего сложного и неудобного нет, дело привычки. Многие вещи наоборот мышкой делать очень неудобно

Comment: @Avbat мне кажется, что если человек только начал изучение, то ему придется столкнуться с тем что вы пишете только через годик-два.

Comment: _настойка окружения для того же js, опять требует манипуляций с ком.строкой_ - что за настройка для js? Интерпретация (грубо говоря - выполнение) JavaScript кода происходит "в браузере". Никакая настройка не нужна.

Comment: @not a Programmer имелся ввиду вот этот курс, собственно после него я понял, что Линукс это не мое в ближайшее время. https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/js-setup-environment и вот эта статья https://guides.hexlet.io/development-on-windows/

Comment: Если Вы новичок, то лучше читать книги, а не онлайн "курсы" проходить.

Comment: @not a Programmer ну в процессе выбора направления, быстрее пробежаться по курсам, чтоб увидеть что да как и насколько оно интересно. Согласен, что курсы дают не так много полезного, как книги, но все же книги требуют больше времени, к ним я перейду, когда пойму, что вот js это мое на ближайшее время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Командная строка - необязательно. Конечно, бывает полезно работать из cmd, и в будущем это возможно пригодится, но сейчас вы будете запускать все программы из [IDE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8). Для разработки вам (очень?)долгое время не потребуется linux, так что можете не заморачиваться.

Одна из лучших IDE для Java - [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows).  Для JS - [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).